# Why my list JSON response is getting atribute @ref and not an object? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, list, ref

I'm getting @ref value on atribute "usuario" on my list JSON response, the second row on, this is repeated, what's happening?:

```js
1 row
{"@id":"1","id":4,"apelido":"HB20","usuario":
{"@id":"2","id":10,"nome":"teste","cpf":null,"telefone":null,"celular":null,"email":"teste@teste.com.br"}}

2 row
{"@id":"3","id":5,"apelido":"Ford","usuario":
{"@ref":"2"}}

3 row
(....)
```

My getVeiculos:

```js
VeiculoService.getVeiculos = function(idUsuario) {
      var dfd = $q.defer();
      $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: options.api.base_url + '/usuario/'+ idUsuario+'/veiculos/' ,
          cache: false
          }).then(function(data) {
              dfd.resolve(data.data);
          }, function(error) {
                dfd.reject(error);
       });

       return dfd.promise;
};
```

My tr with ng-repeat:

```html
<tr ng-repeat='veiculo in data'>
 <td>
   {{veiculo}}
 </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, I was using com.voodoodyne.jackson.jsog.JSOGGenerator on bean.